# adding a tooltip to the 2nd backgroud url in html form input

Tags: html, css

I have been hustling with this for couple of days, and I can't seem to figure out a good way to add a tool tip to the background url, I have two images in background, far left is a user icon and far right is help icon. I am looking forward to add a tooltip or title on mouse hover over only to the tooltip.png icon which is located to the far right.
can anyone suggest a better way to implement this.

following is the code

```css
input[type=text], input[type=p] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 46px;
}
input[type=text] {
    background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/user.png') 10px center no-repeat, url('http://visiblearea.com/blog/pub/System/JQueryPlugin/plugins/tooltip/tooltip-bubble-reverse.png') right 10px center no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px, 15px, 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Username or Email" padding="10px">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: I have added the answer look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type=text], input[type=p] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 46px;
    z-index:-1;
}
input[type=text] {
    background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/user.png') 10px center no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px, 15px, 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
img{
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
  top:20px;
}
#username{
position:relative;
}
.tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    right:15px;
    z-index: 1;
}

img:hover + .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
 
        <form id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
           <div id="username">
          <img src="http://visiblearea.com/blog/pub/System/JQueryPlugin/plugins/tooltip/tooltip-bubble-reverse.png" width=20px; height=20px;>
             <span class="tooltiptext">You have to enter username</span>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Username or Email" padding="10px">
          </div>
        </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that may help you out with this.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp